# Pass in class type to be used with Object Mapper

Tags: ios, swift, generics, objectmapper

I am using the object mapper for swift and have run into a problem.

I have a API class which does a call to the server and responds with a json response.

Now when i call the dataTask function in this API class, i want to pass through the class type i want the json response to be  mapped to using Object mapper.

```
func dataTask(method: String, type: AnyClass) {

    Mapper<AnyClass>().map(response)

}
```

I am not sure how I can pass in the class to be used with the mapper, I have tried generics but not sure if i implemented it correctly or not.

```
func dataTask<T>(method: String, type: T.type) {
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't write `-> Void`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a function that's generic over any `Mappable` type. Essentially, this will produce one version of `dataTask(method:_:)` for every type `T` you use it with, which will call the appropriate version of `Mapper()`.

```
func dataTask<T: Mappable>(method: String, _: T.Type) {
    Mapper<T>().map(response)
}
```

Note the second argument, in order to make it as a generic type its needed to add ".Type".

Comment: I did try that, but got an error stating. Type "T" does not conform to protocol Mappable

Comment: @JackOfDiamonds So then add a generic constraint on `T`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'd recommend expanding your answer to include an explanation of how your code solves the problem.

Comment: @brandonscript I don't think I could. I'll defer to the language guide, who can explain this stuff much better than I.

Comment: Hrm alright. Do what you can. Someone flagged it for content, and without some context, it's not completely clear how this will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderMomchliov, worked a treat, I now somehow understand generics a little bit.

Comment: how to call this function?

Comment: @AlvinJohn You pass the metatype: `dataTask(method: "Some string", SomeType.self)`